# DDP PyTorch model not training

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu

I am trying to implement a PyTorch DDP multi-GPU training script using LeNet-5 CNN and MNIST dataset as:

```
def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'

    # initialize the process group
    dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank = rank, world_size = world_size)


def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()

class LeNet5(nn.Module):
    '''
    Implements a variation of LeNet-5 CNN. It is LeNet-4.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet5, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels = 1, out_channels = 6,
            kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
            stride = 1
        )
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels = 6, out_channels = 16,
            kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
            stride = 1
        )
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels = 16, out_channels = 120,
            kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
            stride = 1
        )
        
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(
            kernel_size = 2, stride = 2
        )
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        # self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features = 512, out_features = 256)
        # self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features = 120, out_features = 84)
        # self.op = nn.Linear(in_features = 84, out_features = 10)
        self.op = nn.Linear(in_features = 1080, out_features = 10)
        
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = self.flatten(x)
        return self.op(x)


def demo_basic(rank, world_size):
    print(f"Running basic DDP example on rank {rank}.")
    setup(rank, world_size)

    # Get MNIST data-
    train_loader, test_loader, train_dataset, test_dataset = get_mnist_dataset(
        path_to_files = "/home/majumdar/Downloads/.data/", batch_size = 1024,
        pin_memory = False, num_workers = 4
    )

    # create model and move it to GPU with id rank
    # model = ToyModel().to(rank)
    model = LeNet5().to(rank)
    ddp_model = DDP(model, device_ids = [rank])

    # Define cost function and optimizer-
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(params = ddp_model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

    num_epochs = 20
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # One epoch of training-
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0.0
        
        for images, labels in train_loader:
            images = images.to(rank)
            labels = labels.to(rank)
            
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # outputs = ddp_model(torch.randn(20, 10))
            outputs = ddp_model(images)
            # labels = torch.randn(20, 5).to(rank)
            # loss_fn(outputs, labels).backward()
            J = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
            J.backward()
            
            optimizer.step()
    
            # Compute model's performance statistics-
            running_loss += J.item() * images.size(0)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(predicted == labels.data)
    
        # Compute training loss and accuracy for one epoch-
        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
        epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / len(train_dataset)
    
        print(f"epoch: {epoch + 1}; loss = {epoch_loss:.4f} & acc = {epoch_acc * 100:.2f}%")

    cleanup()



def run_demo(demo_fn, world_size):
    mp.spawn(
        demo_fn,
        args = (world_size,),
        nprocs = world_size,
        join = True
        )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
    assert n_gpus >= 2, f"Requires at least 2 GPUs to run, but got {n_gpus}"
    world_size = n_gpus
    run_demo(demo_basic, world_size)
```

But at the end of 20 epochs of training, the model achieves an accuracy of 1.10% which is dreadful. If I run the same code without DDP multi-GPU training, then the accuracy achieved is close to 95%.

What am I missing?